# How to see JSP errors in the Problem view in Eclipse + WTP

Tags: eclipse, jsp, eclipse-wtp

I have installed WTP into Eclipse Galileo. When I open up my JSPs, I get red markers indicating syntax or compile errors. However, I do not see these markers in the Navigator, Package Explorer or the Problems views. Is there a way to see which JSPs have problems in any/ all of these views?

Answer (score 1):

Your project needs to have the Validation Builder installed for the Problem Markers to be created/updated.  The Properties dialog on your project should have a Validation page offering the ability to add this Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you project is not dynamic web project.

Try to create a sample "dynamic web project" and see what happens.